# Laravel view Undefined variable: sand_cmonths, I'm new to laravel and PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

**I've searched a lot but it no help;
I'm using laravel 7 with MySQL DB, I'm new to PHP and Laravel**

**This is controller:**

```
class SandController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $sand = Sand::latest()->paginate(10);
        $sand_cmonths = DB::table('sand')
                     ->select(DB::raw('cmonth'))
                     ->groupBy('cmonth')
                     ->get();  
        return view('sand.index')->with(compact('sand','sand_cmonths'));
    }
    public function search(Request $req){

        $search = $req->get('search');

        $sand = DB::table('sand')
             ->where('vehicle_number','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
             ->orWhere('bill_number', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
             ->orWhere('per_ton_rate', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
             ->orWhere('total_weight', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
             ->orWhere('total_rate', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
             ->paginate(10);

        return view('sand.index',['sand'=>$sand], compact('search'));
    }
}
```

**These are my routes**

```
Route::resource('sand','SandController');
Route::get('/sand','SandController@search')->name('sand.search');
```

ALSO WHEN I DISABLE THE SEARCH ROUTE EVRYTHING WORKS FINE, THE 2ND VARIABLE $SAND_CMONTHS WORKS

Comment: You can't use same URI prefix. here `/sand` and `/sand` are the same prefix. I suggest you Change the second route URI prefix , like  `Route::get('/search/sand','SandController@search')->name('sand.search');`

Comment: But i need the search route on the same page, when i change the route it takes me to a blank not found page

Comment: The "/sand" in Route::get('/sand','SandController@search') is the default route to the index method of your controller place the Route::get('/sand','SandController@search')->name('sand.search') above the Route:: resource or you change the "/sand" to something else

Comment: If you do that then it will conflict with your resource index method `sand.index` Know more about resource controller from here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are defining a `resource` route `Laravel` is setting some routes by default.
When you define the following:

```
Route::resource('sand','SandController');
```

Laravel is automatically creating a get route like the following:

```
Route::get('/sand','SandController@index');
```

So you can see the route you are using for search is already defined. So when ever you are calling the route for search `Route::get('/sand','SandController@index');`  this route is being called first and it is hitting the `index` method. Thus the `sand_cmonths` variable error.
I would suggest you to change the name of your search route something like the following:

```
Route::get('/sand-search','SandController@search')->name('sand.search');
```

This should work fine.

Comment: it takes me to sand-search, which is a blank page

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined variable: sand_cmonths

Comment: If you want to send the search results to the index page. Then you have to name the variable the same name.

Comment: Add the following line in your `search` function:
`$sand_cmonths = DB::table('sand')
                     ->select(DB::raw('cmonth'))
                     ->groupBy('cmonth')
                     ->get();`